# How do you print chunked output with curl?

Tags: shell, curl

I can see chunked output as it arrives with:

```
curl http://asia.dabase.com:4000
```

However when I try loop and work with it like so:

```
curl -s http://asia.dabase.com:4000 | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

It doesn't print anything. :(

A previous answer suggests [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7202947/4534), though I don't see how that's done from curl's manpage.

Comment: seems to be working, is the url you are trying to curl return binary contents ?

Comment: Are you able to print output via the while loop?

Comment: Yup, is OK for me when using another URL. Are you sure the URL is working ?

Comment: `curl http://asia.dabase.com:4000` works for me :)

Comment: but does not work for me, the page is hang, and no output being returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since taken the site `asia.dabase.com` down, though I have found the solution using a tool I've never heard of until now called `stdbuf`.

```
stdbuf -oL curl -s http://asia.dabase.com:4000
```

This allows me to immediately start working with a chunked stream.