# MultiCurl requires big timeout in order to fetch data from many URLs

Tags: php, curl

I use this multi curl wrapper: https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/

I'm looping through ~160 URLs and fetch XML data from them. As I realize the curl requests are done in parallel. The strange thing is that if I put small timeout (say, 10 seconds) more than half of URLs couldn't be handled: I received error callback with error message of `Timeout was reached`.

However if I set the timeout to be 100 seconds, almost all URLs are handled properly.

But I cannot understand why this happens. If I use a single Curl instance and fetch data from any of the URLs I got response pretty quickly, it doesn't require 100 seconds to fetch data from a single URL.

So the purpose of multi curl is doing requests in parallel. Every request has it's own timeout. Then, if the timeout is set to small value (10-20-30 seconds), then why it turns out that it's not enough?

Later I'll have ~600 URLs, which would mean that the timeout probably should be increased to 400-500 seconds, which is weird. I could as well create a single Curl instance and do requests one by one with almost the same results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number of cURL connections set by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850951/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-curl-connections-set-by)

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS.html

Comment: @JoseManuelVillasanteArmas Are you open to using a different PHP library? It use curl in background, but a much cleaner interface

Answer (score 0):

> **Curl** and **PHP** can't async a request

instead of using **fetch** in a **JavaScript** way you got second third ... chance to do the job with **promises**. however to add this native function to php with curl you go somes ways already talked here [Async curl request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171222/async-curl-request-in-php) and [PHP Curl async response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198966/php-curl-async-response)